# Why doesn't Thor's hammer return to his hand on Earth? (Avengers - The movie)

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, the-avengers-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Was Thor unworthy during “The Avengers”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/was-thor-unworthy-during-the-avengers)

This question 
[Why did Thor's hammer take time to return from the Helicarrier?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16552/why-did-thors-hammer-take-time-to-return-from-the-helicarrier) provoked another question in my mind.

When he breaks the container he's in and gets up from the crash-landing onto Earth, why didn't Thor's hammer return to his hand when he reaches for it?

Comment: Not duplicate: My question's just stated as an observation  there. Also,it doesn't provide me with an answer to my question.

Comment: How does `But at that moment, he felt had to go to it, for he didn't feel worthy` not answer your question?

Comment: I have upvoted because its cleaner question than that one, but it's indeed a duplicate. Voting to close..

Comment: I agree that this appears to be a duplicate.  Only, I suggest this one (already mentioned in the OP here):  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16552/1639  The questions themselves are phrased differently, but really are asking about the same thing.  Mjölnir's apparent delay in return, according to the current answer in the other thread, is not because it *wasn't* returning - just that it needed time to do so.

Comment: @Iszi This one and the one you linked aren't talking about the same thing at all.  This question is about the scene where Thor crash lands and walks to his hammer which landed a few yards from him.  He then picks it up instead of calling it to him.

Comment: @Keen I just saw the movie last weekend, and don't recall that particular interaction.  I guess now I have *another* excuse to go see it again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's a little unclear, I believe that scene is meant to imply that Thor is essentially receiving a vision...

> The dissolve to Banner, then the Helicarrier, showing the conclusion and aftermath of the battle are all bracketed by Thor reaching for his hammer, then pausing for some reason that is admittedly unclear, then finally picking up the hammer with resolve and calling the lightning to armour himself (until that point, his arms were bare, but the scaled armour begins to form itself as he calls the lightning).

So my interpretation of the scene is that he reaches for the hammer, pauses to process the vision he's received, then continues with renewed purpose. But I'll agree it could have been clearer.